# How to break lines in messages in markdown / knitr?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

I want to create a vignette for an R package using markdown (`knitr`) and pdf output. Some of my functions produce messages that are nicely broken into lines in the console. However, in the resulting pdf, the lines are not fit into the box for the code chunk but overflow.

I tried using `strwrap` and `writeLines` within `message` with width = 80 (see examples). It does break the lines at the right places, but I have to use `con = stdout()` in `writeLines` to see the output in the markdown pdf.

`con = stderr()` (the default) does not show the message. However, this way, the console output is no longer formatted the same way as normal messages (red in my case) but like normal output (black).

```r
mes <- "A very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long message."

# default settings 
message(mes)

# using writeLines and strwrap
message(writeLines(strwrap(mes, width = 80, con = stderr()))
message(writeLines(strwrap(mes, width = 80), con = stdout())
```

Here are the results in the R console

[image: console]

and in the markdown pdf:

[image: markdown pdf]

My preferred solution would be not to format the messages but to find the correct hack for markdown / knitr.

Comment: [This example on wrapping text](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/077-wrap-output.Rmd) may be what you are after. (Which I saw in an answer to [this question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-knit-to-pdf-how-to-wrap-long-lines/14829) at RStudio Community).

Comment: This goes into the right direction. However, it only gives the first line formatted as output, the rest as normal R code. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use `writeLines`, I'd do the wrapping and then pass the string to `message`.  For example,

```
mes <- "A very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long message."

# default settings 
message(mes)

# pasted together
message(paste(strwrap(mes, width = 80), collapse = "\n"))
```

That's cumbersome to write each time, so if you're doing it often, I'd put it in a function:

```
wrapmessage <- function(mes, width = 80) 
 message(paste(strwrap(mes, width = width), collapse = "\n"))
```

and then use it like this:

```
wrapmessage(mes)      # 80 chars
wrapmessage(mes, 40)  # 40 chars
```

The latter looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Great, this would work! However, I really would like to not hard code the width of the message text but to find a knitr solution.

Comment: That's probably hard:  the width of the box in characters depends on all sorts of things like font, text width, etc.  Those are known to LaTeX, and theoretically you could calculate them in `knitr` since it sets the font and page size, but it wouldn't be easy.  I'd probably do it by trial and error until I found a width I liked, then hard code that one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution following aosmith's suggestion using hook_outputs. I had to redefine it compared to the example given in the link to apply to messages, not the general output:

```
hook_output = knit_hooks$get('message')
knit_hooks$set(message = function(x, options) {
  # this hook is used only when the linewidth_mes option is not NULL
  if (!is.null(n <- options$linewidth_mes)) {
    x = knitr:::split_lines(x)
    # any lines wider than n should be wrapped
    if (any(nchar(x) > n)) x = strwrap(x, width = n)
    x = paste(x, collapse = '\n')
  }
  hook_output(x, options)
})
```

However, I also realized that the formatting and if it works correctly strongly depends on the character defined for comments in `opts_chunk$set`.